# Is it possible to factor using/writing with a bufio.Writer?

Tags: go

Either I have to write an int16 like this:

```
delay :=  uint16(200)
buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
err = binary.Write(buf, encoding, delay)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprint("binary.Write failed:", err))
}
_, _ = writer.Write(buf.Bytes())
```

...or and int64 like this:

```
nbObjects :=  uint64(len(myArray))
buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
err = binary.Write(buf, encoding, nbObjects)
_, _ = writer.Write(buf.Bytes())
```

..or a string like this:

```
now := []byte(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700"))
buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
err = binary.Write(buf, encoding, now)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprint("binary.Write failed:", err))
}
_, _ = writer.Write(buf.Bytes())
```

And I might have a lot of things to do but the same "shared" code is always:

```
buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
err = binary.Write(buf, encoding, [my variable])
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprint("binary.Write failed:", err))
}
_, _ = writer.Write(buf.Bytes())
```

Is there a way to "generalize" this, and thus to have a "final" code like this:

```
uint16(200).write(writer, encoding)
uint64(len(myArray)).write(writer, encoding)
[]byte(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700")).write(writer, encoding)
```

(maybe it's not possible, I'm just wondering if I'll have to copy/paste my code each time I have to write something to `writer()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function to avoid copy/paste of similar code:

```
func write(writer io.Writer, encoding binary.ByteOrder, value interface{}) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, encoding, value)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprint("binary.Write failed:", err))
    }
    _, _ = writer.Write(buf.Bytes())
}
```

Call it like this:

```
write(writer, encoding, uint16(200))
```

Because the bytes.Buffer is not needed, the write function can simplified to:

```
func write(writer io.Writer, encoding binary.ByteOrder, value interface{}) {
    err := binary.Write(writer, encoding, value)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprint("binary.Write failed:", err))
    }
}
```

This version of the functions changes how errors are handled. The code in the question ignores errors returned from `writer.Write`.  This version panics when an error is returned from writer.Write.

If you want to handle errors more gracefully than panicking, then call binary.Write directly:

```
err := binary.Write(writer, encoding, value)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

In this snippet, `value` can be `uint16(200)`, `uint64(len(myArray))`, etc.

Comment: I come from the `C` world. In `C`, you precise *explicitely* if it's a pointer, or a value. Not hard to guess, code easy to read. Here, even though your example might work, correct me if I'm wrong, but it *can* be either a value (`uint16()`...) *or* a pointer to a memory location (`[]byte()`). I dont get that. I mean.. I dont get how you can know what type of data you can pass to a parameter.

Comment: The `value` argument is an `interface{}`. [Interfaces are covered in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9).  The binary.Write function [uses a type switch](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3dd58676054223962cd915bb0934d1f9f489d4d2/src/encoding/binary/binary.go#L275) to branch to type specific encoding code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `interface {}` seems the way to go for a lot of things in Go.